# Prevent debian 10 from waking up from suspend when bluetooth headphone turns on

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth, suspend

Ever since i upgraded to Debian 10 (buster), the computer wakes up from sleep / suspend when i turn on my bluetooth headset (Sends a request to connect to computer i believe).
How do i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution through systemd service: (`/etc/systemd/system/bluetoothKillOnSuspend.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth TurnOff on suspend
Before=suspend.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rfkill block bluetooth

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Enable it by: `systemctl enable bluetoothKillOnSuspend.service`

This script blocks Bluetooth while suspended. For me, it is unblocked automatically on wake-up, so didn't have to create a new script to unblock Bluetooth after suspend.